# C++ including python.h and boost/python.hpp causes SEH exception

Tags: python, c++, boost

I've recently stumbled across something while trying to fix the python implementation in the c++ software I'm working on. If you have the following included:

```
#include <python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

then the following code causes an SEH Exception with a memory access violation:

```
boost::python::object mainModule;

Py_Initialize();

std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(PythonAccessMutex);
this->mainModule = boost::python::import("__main__");

boost::python::dict globalDict = boost::python::extract<boost::python::dict>(this->mainModule.attr("__dict__"));
```

Removing the python.h include resolved my issue but I've been unable to find out why this was causing the exception and I'd like to be able to share with my coworkers why they shouldn't do this (past the obvious reason of it breaks the code)

I should be specific and point out that the code runs fine until it hits the extract function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are macro conflicts if `Python.h` is included before a Boost.Python header.  For instance, `Python.h` includes `LongObject.h` defining `ULONGLONG_MAX` that confuses Boost's config.  The inclusion issue is noted in [`detail/prefix.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/boost-1.57.0/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp):

> The rule is that `<Python.h>` must be included before any system headers (so it can get control over some awful macros). Unfortunately, Boost.Python needs to `#include <limits.h>` first, at least... but this gets us as close as possible.

After some setup work, [`detail/wrap_python.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/boost-1.57.0/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp) includes `Python.h`.