# C++ Boost::Python Py_Initialize throwing Assertion Failed on object.c

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am trying to embed the Python 3.5 interpreter in a C++ program with Boost 1.76.0. While doing this, I am having issues as the program throws an assertion failed at the `Py_Initialize();`

```
Assertion failed: (op->_ob_prev == NULL) == (op->_ob_next == NULL), file ..\Objects\object.c, line 84
```

The minimal code in which this happens is as follows:

```cpp
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        Py_Initialize();
    }
    catch (boost::python::error_already_set& e)
    {
        PyErr_PrintEx(0);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Looking online I found other few occurrences with no answers tho. Any ideas why this is happening?

---

As it turns out, the include order is important. I could not find any notes on this on the Boost documentation and examples, so I will add this here: putting the `#include <Python.h>` before the `#include <boost/python.hpp>` fixed the issue for me.

If anyone has some insight on how this happens, please feel free to add more details.

I also found this ([C++ including python.h and boost/python.hpp causes SEH exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369489/c-including-python-h-and-boost-python-hpp-causes-seh-exception)) so I don't know if I am just lucky it works, if this has been fixed in later versions of Boost or something else.

**Update 1**: Trying to just remove `#include <Python.h>` causes the error to present itself again. Is this a Boost bug/compilation issue?

**Update 2**: I have indeed incountered an issue as said in the aforementioned question, in particular when importing a python script. So I am back to mile 0, does anyone have any ideas?

**Update 3**: I tried to use precompiled DLLs, use other versions of Python, but I still keep getting this issue. I am really at a loss of ideas.

Comment: Did you compile your boost-python with the same version/interpreter of the Python.h you are including?

Comment: @mdf Yes, I tried to rebuild it specifying the Python installation and it still gives this issue